# Optimize my Python code to make it work on a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files. The first (of 24MO) contains the scores of two keywords, here's a simple :

```
{'civil_right': [], 'finance': [('spending', 8.420475110400954)],'free': [('free_transport', 10.466459719664448), ('free_principles', 10.466459719664448), ('free_administration', 10.466459719664448), ('free_services', 10.466459719664448), ('salary', 10.466459719664448)]}
```

The second is a text file of 400MO, basically raw text.Here's a sample :

```
chapter 5 the allotment
definition of the subdivision November 2014 buffer 180435 June 2019
1 presentation. for common sense, the housing estate evokes suburban housing, that of the suburbs of big cities after the first war, but also, today, that of new districts in small towns and villages that push back the frontier of natural space. these are places where houses are juxtaposed which, without being identical, have "a family resemblance", as professor bouyssou put it. for the candidate builder, the allotment is first of all the possibility to acquire a serviced land in order to build a house adapted to his tastes and needs, of which he will be able to "choose the plans", subject, possibly, to the respect of a regulation coming to specify the provisions of the town-planning plan of the commune. it can be, later, the obligation to take part in the maintenance of the common equipments as a member of a trade-union association of owners and to respect certain rules of collective life specified in a schedule of conditions.
```

I want to find for every pair of keywords that are in the first file, the longest sentence they appear together from the second file. For example, the longest sentence that contains (finance, spending), (free,free_transport), (free,free_principles),(free,free_administration),(free,free_services),(free,salary). I choose the longest sentence because those two words may appear together in several sentences in my text; so I will choose the longest one.

Here's what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import ast
import itertools
from tqdm import tqdm

#Reading data as list
hp = [line.strip() for line in open('text_file.txt', encoding='utf8')] 
#filter None elements from list
hp = list(filter(None,hp))
hp = [i.split('.') for i in hp]
hp = [i.strip() for l in hp for i in l]
keywords = [line for line in open('keywords_score_file.txt', encoding='utf8')]
keywords = ast.literal_eval(keywords[0])
word_pairs = []

for k,v in keywords.items():
    if v:
        word_pairs.append((k,v[0][0]))

word_pairs = list(set([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in word_pairs]))

df = pd.DataFrame(hp)
df.columns = ['text']

#The treatment
final_dict = {}

for wp in tqdm(word_pairs):
    #finding the length of sentence which contains the word pair else return 0
    df['length'] = df.apply(lambda row:len(row['text']) if all(map(row['text'].__contains__,wp)) else 0,axis=1)
    #check if we have sentence which contains word pair
    if len(df[df['length']>0]):
        #insert the word pair as key and the longest sentence as value in the final dictionary
        final_dict[wp] = df['text'].iloc[df[df['length']>0].length.idxmax()]
    #drop the length column created for above purpose
    df.drop(['length'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

This works for a sample of my data, but I let it run the entire night for my entire text and it only treated 1167 pair of keywords among 20507. How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example and see if it will speed things up:

I added one sentence in addition to your sample to file.txt to see if the script works:

```
chapter 5 the allotment
definition of the subdivision November 2014 buffer 180435 June 2019
1 presentation. for common sense, the housing estate evokes suburban housing, that of the suburbs of big cities after the first war, but also, today, that of new districts in small towns and villages that push back the frontier of natural space. these are places where houses are juxtaposed which, without being identical, have "a family resemblance", as professor bouyssou put it. for the candidate builder, the allotment is first of all the possibility to acquire a serviced land in order to build a house adapted to his tastes and needs, of which he will be able to "choose the plans", subject, possibly, to the respect of a regulation coming to specify the provisions of the town-planning plan of the commune. it can be, later, the obligation to take part in the maintenance of the common equipments as a member of a trade-union association of owners and to respect certain rules of collective life specified in a schedule of conditions.

This is finance, salary, free.
```

---

The script:

```
keywords = {'civil_right': [], 'finance': [('spending', 8.420475110400954)],'free': [('free_transport', 10.466459719664448), ('free_principles', 10.466459719664448), ('free_administration', 10.466459719664448), ('free_services', 10.466459719664448), ('salary', 10.466459719664448)]}

# generate all keyword-pairs
all_keywords = set()
word_pairs = []
for k, v in keywords.items():
    for vv in v:
        word_pairs.append((k, vv[0]))
        all_keywords.add(k)
        all_keywords.add(vv[0])

# load file
lines, lines_map = [], {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue
        for l in map(str.strip, line.split('.')):
            if not l:
                continue
            lines.append(l)
            # generate `lines_map` for current line number:
            for k in all_keywords:
                if k in l:
                    lines_map.setdefault(k, {})[len(lines)-1] = len(l)


for a, b in word_pairs:
    common_keys = lines_map.get(a, {}).keys() & lines_map.get(b, {}).keys()
    if common_keys:
        max_k = max(common_keys, key=lambda k: lines_map[a][k])
        print(a, b, max_k)
        print(lines[max_k])
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
free salary 7
This is finance, salary, free
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```